# In CSS how do I make a page link change colour to represent what page im currently on?

Tags: html, css, web

At the moment I have my links in a NAV bar but when I arrive on say the gallery page I want the gallery link to change to another colour to represnt which page the user is currently on, how do I do this in CSS?

Comment: I am not a magician give me a code

Comment: You don't do this in CSS only: CSS only carries the style, not the 'intelligence'. Basically, you'll add a class on the link of the current page, and this class will carry some style to highlight your link.

Comment: @JoshuaLC so you want the navbar to show what page you are currently on, right?

Comment: @JoelBanks yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is to have the currently active page to be a different color, to show the user what page they are on. You should be able to do this with .active code and set a background color for when it is active. [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp) is a nice w3schools link about navbars, hopefully this helps.

Comment: active changes colour when clicked!, I want the text to change colour when currently on the page.

Answer (score 0):

What are you using for your routing? Is it just static navigation to html pages or are you handing routing on client-side/server-side? Either way, use ids and classes on your link element and set class "active" (or any other name) to an appropriate id. Style active class accordingly.

Comment: I’m doing it static, that just makes all links change colour permanently & not when on the specific page.

Comment: That's why you'd have an "active" class, applied to specific link which would have a specified colour. You'd set your class on desired element on each page.

Comment: So I would add it to each html page?, sorry confused for a second sorry.

Comment: If you are using just HTML and your nav is hardcoded on each html page, then set the class "active" on each link that represents the page. Then just style that class for your desired preferences.

Comment: I strongly urge you to take a look at frameworks like AngularJS and its routing. You would achieve great results without having to manage multiple redundant page sections. Setting active nav items would be very easy. Take a look at a very basic example here: https://ciphertrick.com/2016/07/26/build-single-page-application-angular-2/

Comment: I did that but links still aren’t changing colour

Comment: Here's an example for you: https://jsfiddle.net/kirillinfinite/w7kj1zov/

Answer (score 0):

1) As the comments already said, this isn't done in CSS, CSS doesn't have the required logic.

2) An example site for what you want, some code snippets for what you have tried, or some pictures of what you are looking for would help you get better answers.

3) `click` in javascript/jquery is generally where this is handled.
https://jsfiddle.net/a5609kgL/1/

4) You can also compare `window.location.href`to all the link targets in javascript/jquery, but this is not recommended.
https://jsfiddle.net/a5609kgL/3/

> Note: After clicking the second link you have to click the 'Run' button.